# Prove using the resolution method that : $\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3 \models \varphi_4 $

Tags: logic

I have to prove using the resolution method that :

$\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3 \models \varphi_4 $ where:

$\varphi_1 = \exists z\, \forall x\, ( \forall y\, (q(g(x),y) \vee p(z,g(x))) $

$\varphi_2 = \exists z\, \forall y\, ( p(y,g(g(y)) \rightarrow \forall x\, q(x, g(z))) $

$\varphi_3 = \forall x\, \forall y\, ( r(x, g(y)) \rightarrow (r(g(y),x) \vee \neg \exists x\, \exists y\, r(x,y)))  $

$\varphi_4 = \exists z\, ( \exists x\, q(g(x), z) \wedge \exists x\, q(z,x)) $

I know that I have to use the method on $\varphi_1 \wedge \varphi_2 \wedge \varphi_3 \wedge  \neg \varphi_4 $, but from there on I have no idea what to do. Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: you need to $\land$ the four statements, not $\lor$!

Comment: $\models$ can be typeset using \models.

Comment: @user3719857  Do you have the resolution algorithm? Can you describe it to us step by step, and show us where you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

See [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique) procedure :

*(i)* All sentences in the knowledge base and the negation of the sentence to be proved (the conjecture) are conjunctively connected.

*(ii)* The resulting sentence is transformed into a [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) with the conjuncts viewed as elements in a set of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

Consider e.g. the negated conclusion $\lnot \varphi_4$:

> $¬ ∃z [ ∃x q(g(x),z) ∧ ∃xq(z,x) ]$.

It can be rewritten as :

> $∀z ¬ [ ∃x q(g(x),z) ∧ ∃wq(z,w) ] \equiv ∀z [ ∀x ¬ q(g(x),z) ∨ ∀w ¬ q(z,w) ]$.

Then: *(iii)* convert it to [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conversion_to_prenex_form):

> $∀z∀x∀w [  ¬ q(g(x),z) ∨ ¬ q(z,w) ]$,

and finally: *(iv)* [Skolemize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form):

> > $¬ q(g(x),z) ∨ ¬ q(z,w)$.

This is one of the needed *clauses*.

Same for the four premise; for example, for $\varphi_1$ we have :

> $q(g(x),y) ∨ p(c_1,g(x))$.

After completion of the preliminary work of transformation, we have to apply the [resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) trying to derive the *empty clause* : $\square$.

---

*Note.* The *empty clause* (symbolized : $\square$ or $\{ \}$) is an empty disjunction and the convention is that an empty disjunction is always *false*. Thus, we may symbolize it also with: $\bot$ (the *falsum*).

The convention is justified by the fact that : $A \lor B \lor \bot \equiv A \lor B$, i.e. adding an empty disjunction to an existing disjunction does not alter its truth value.